# Enable/disable a button if another one is clicked in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object, angularjs-ng-disabled

I have the first group 3 buttons: `line`, `spline` and `bar`.

The second group: `single`, `double` and `triple`.

What I want to do it to make the second group buttons to be enabled or disabled depending on which one from the first group is clicked like this:

- if `line` is clicked all three (`single`, `double` and `triple`)  are enabled
- if `spline` of `bar` is clicked only `single` is enabled, `double` and `triple` are disabled.

This is the array of objects I'm using (probably it could be a better way to organize it):

```
myList = [
    { name: 'Line', icon:'line', subList: [{ name : 'Single', icon:'a' },
                                           { name : 'Double', icon: 'b' },
                                           { name : 'Triple', icon: 'c' }]},
    { name : 'Spline', icon: 'spline', subList: [{ name: 'Single', icon:'a' }]},
    { name : 'Bar', icon: 'bar', subList: [{ name: 'Single', icon:'c' }] }
];
```

Here I generate the first group of buttons:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
  <i ng-repeat="view in $ctrl.myList"
     ng-class="$ctrl.isViewSet(view) ? 'btn-primary' : 'btn-default'"
     ng-click="!$ctrl.disableViews && $ctrl.setView(view)"
     ng-disabled="$ctrl.disableViews">
  </i>
</div>
```

This is the second one:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-sm btn-group-comparison">
  <i ng-repeat="view in $ctrl.myList[0].subList"
     class="btn yp-pulseIcon-{{view.icon}}"
     ng-click="!$ctrl.disableViews && $ctrl.setView(view)"
     ng-disabled="$ctrl.disableViews">
  </i>
</div>
```

I guess that on the second one I must modify something in `ng-disabled` but all that I've tried so far doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using ng-disabled to enable/disable button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38765784/using-ng-disabled-to-enable-disable-button)

Comment: You need to set up a plunker or fiddle as we have no idea what you have going on in the methods. But basically you need to pass in the selected view to the select method and have the disabled attribute of the second set of buttons act on the `view.subList` of that selected item

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `ng-repeat` to enumerate through the lists to generate the buttons? This would be a lot easier to do if you add each button individually in the HTML. Then you can apply certain conditions using `ng-disabled` directly. If you do have to do it this way, you can use a JavaScript function in your controller to handle this.

Comment: @RobynCute I think I can do it without `ng-repeat` but I don't know with what I must replace the <i ng-repeat> line...

Comment: @user3654571 I'm saying if you place each button individually in the HTML like: `<i class="$ctrl.isViewSet('Line','line') ? 'btn-primary' : 'btn-default'" ng-click="!$ctrl.disableViews && $ctrl.setView('Line','line')"
     ng-disabled="$ctrl.disableViews"></i>` for example for the first button (I'm guessing about your JS functions and passed the name and icon of the `view` instead of the view object itself) instead of enumerating through `myList`. 
You'd have an `<i></i>` item for each item in `myList`. That is essentially what `ng-reat` does.
This is just an idea.